# service class not found error in laravel 4.2?

Tags: laravel

Attached Image shows exact my problem:
[image: Attached Image shows exact my problem]
**Given below is my app.php where providers array is defined.****This is laravel 4.2.**

```
 'providers' => array(

        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\CommandsServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\MigrationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Remote\RemoteServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\ReminderServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Database\SeedServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider',
        'Illuminate\Workbench\WorkbenchServiceProvider',
        'FanzoopMain\Theme\Provider\ThemeServiceProvider',
        'Creolab\LaravelModules\ServiceProvider',
        'FanzoopMain\Menu\MenuServiceProvider',
        'FanzoopMain\Image\ImageServiceProvider',
        'FanzoopMain\Hook\HookServiceProvider',
        /**
        * App base
        */
        'App\Providers\ConfigurationServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\AddonServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\PhotoServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\AdmincpServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ThemeManagerServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\NotificationServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\MentionServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\HashtagServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\MenuServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EmoticonServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConnectionServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\PostServiceProvider',
        'Artdarek\OAuth\OAuthServiceProvider',
        'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',
),

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Service Provider Manifest
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The service provider manifest is used by Laravel to lazy load service
| providers which are not needed for each request, as well to keep a
| list of all of the services. Here, you may set its storage spot.
|
*/

'manifest' => storage_path().'/meta',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Aliases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
| is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
| the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
|
*/

'aliases' => array(

        'App'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\App',
        'Artisan'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan',
        'Auth'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',
        'Blade'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade',
        'Cache'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache',
        'ClassLoader'     => 'Illuminate\Support\ClassLoader',
        'Config'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config',
        'Controller'      => 'Illuminate\Routing\Controller',
        'Cookie'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie',
        'Crypt'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt',
        'DB'              => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB',
        'Eloquent'        => 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model',
        'Event'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event',
        'File'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\File',
        'Form'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Form',
        'Hash'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash',
        'HTML'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\HTML',
        'Input'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input',
        'Lang'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang',
        'Log'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',
        'Mail'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail',
        'Paginator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Paginator',
        'Password'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password',
        'Queue'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue',
        'Redirect'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect',
        'Redis'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis',
        'Request'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request',
        'Response'        => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response',
        'Route'           => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route',
        'Schema'          => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema',
        'Seeder'          => 'Illuminate\Database\Seeder',
        'Session'         => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session',
        'SSH'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\SSH',
        'Str'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Str',
        'URL'             => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL',
        'Validator'       => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator',
        'View'            => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\View',


        'OAuth'           => 'Artdarek\OAuth\Facade\OAuth',
        'Addon'           => 'App\Facades\Addon',
        'ThemeManager'    => 'App\Facades\ThemeManager',
        'Excel'           => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',
),
```

This is my another file, named ConfigurationServiceProvider.php, where I am using the error occuring code.

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Providers\ConfigurationServiceProvider;                
/**
 * Configuration service provider
 *
 * @author : Tiamiyu waliu kola
 * @webiste: procrea8.com
 */

class ConfigurationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register(){

    }

    public function boot(){        
        if (\Config::get('system.installed')) {            
            $repository = app('App\Repositories\ConfigurationRepository');

            foreach($repository->getAll() as $configuration) {
                \Config::set($configuration['slug'], $configuration['value']);
            }               
            /**
             * set image configuration
             */
            \Config::set('image::max-size', \Config::get('image-max-size'));
            \Config::set('image::save-original', \Config::get('keep-original-image'));
            \Config::set('image::allow-animated-gif', \Config::get('allow-animated-gif'));
            \Config::set('image::ext-allowed', \Config::get('image-allow-type', 'gif,png,jpg'));


            /**Assets***/
            \Config::set('theme::minifyAssets', \Config::get('minify-assets'));            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you update composer these error is occured??

Comment: Thanks to response.Yes...exact when in update compose..

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Or

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

Make sure you have registered your providers directory on composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
         "app/providers"
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Tty this steps

1. Temporary remove your providers and aliases
2. Type command composer update
3. Then add this providers and aliases

Because when you update composer he try to find this classes before adding in your project, After updating your composer add this classes

Comment: Komal, this is still not working.I followed above all steps accordingly.

Comment: Remove this line   'Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider',     'Excel'           => 'Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel',

Comment: Not solved.. Komal should i send you my app.php file file where i have used all these providers.

One thing also i want to share with you that where i am using all this data,It's beta version .On live site everything working fine.we only transferred the data on subdomain over same domain.

Comment: Ok send me your app.php and composer.json file

Comment: may i have your email?

Comment: yup.. komal2887@gmail.com

Comment: Update composer.json "maatwebsite/excel": "1.*"